# Android Data Binding layout_width and layout_height

Tags: java, android, mvvm, data-binding

I need to be able to dynamically set an EditText's height property. I am using data binding for other properties throughout my app, so I would love to be able to use data binding to control the height of my elements. Here is a stripped down version of my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable name="loginVM" type="com.testing.stuff.ViewModels.LoginViewModel" />
</data>

<EditText android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/txtVerificationCode"
            android:layout_height="@{loginVM.compact ? @dimen/verificationHeightCompact : @dimen/verificationHeightFull}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:alpha="@{loginVM.verificationOpacity}"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:hint="Enter verificationCode"
            android:text="@{loginVM.verificationCode}" />
</layout>
```

And here is a stripped down version of my View Model:

```
public class LoginViewModel extends BaseObservable {
public final ObservableField<String> verificationCode; 
public final ObservableField<Boolean> compact;

@Bindable
public String getVerificationCode() {
    if (this.verificationCode == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return this.verificationCode.get();
    }
}

public void setVerificationCode(String verificationCode) {
    this.verificationCode.set(verificationCode);
    invalidateProperties();
}

@Bindable
public Boolean getCompact(){return this.compact.get();}

public void setCompact(Boolean value)
{
    this.compact.set(value);
    this.invalidateProperties();
}

@BindingAdapter("android:layout_height")
public static void setLayoutHeight(EditText view, float height)
{
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = (int)height;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}

public LoginViewModel(Context ctx) {
    verificationCode = new ObservableField();
    compact = new ObservableField();
}
```

The dimensions are in the dimens.xml file. And I am modifying the properties in the view model. But, when I launch the app, I'm getting the following error immediately after launch (the bindingadapter is not firing on debug). I have several other elements on the screen but this particular one is the one I need to change the height when a particular action occurs:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.testing.stuff, PID: 32752

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  
ComponentInfo{com.testing.stuff/com.testing.stuff.Login}: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #69: You must supply 
a layout_height attribute.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #69: You 
must supply a layout_height attribute.
```

There are a few posts on SO regarding this issue but no definitive answers or the approach did not work. Surely this is an implementation that is common. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: "Surely this is an implementation that is common" -- considering that data binding is still a release candidate, I would not consider *anything* related to data binding to be "common". I would not be surprised if you cannot set the height and width this way, as that data is validated immediately upon inflating the layout, and by that point you won't have injected the model yet, let alone set those attributes. It's possible that there's some workaround, using a synthetic property (e.g., `app:width`) that you apply your binding expression to, that adjusts your view's `LayoutParams`.

Comment: You may be absolutely correct. I guess because of my familiarity with data binding on other platforms(Windows), I just expected it to be commonplace on Android as well.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In Java

```
@BindingAdapter("layout_height")
public static void setLayoutHeight(View view, float height) {
    LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

And in your XML

```
app:layout_height="@{ viewModel.isBig ? @dimen/dp_20 : @dimen/dp_5 }"
```

import the app like this

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: I had to add a default value for it to work android:layout_height="@{smallScreen ? @dimen/dp_20 : @dimen/dp_5, default=wrap_content}"

Comment: @Shubham I don't know when default value will be used. smallScreen only have 2 case (true or false)

Comment: @PhanVanLinh for me it was giving error java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #21: You must supply a layout_width attribute if I didn't add a default value

Comment: don't forget to cast to int `layoutParams.height = height.toInt()` to

Comment: @Shubham You need to provide a default value. `app:layout_height="@{ viewModel.isBig ? @dimen/dp_20 : @dimen/dp_5 , default=wrap_content}"`

Comment: Cannot find a setter for <android.view.View android:layout_height> that accepts parameter type 'float'

Comment: I had to reference @Camino2007's answer below. It worked when I append namespace `android` to `@BindingAdapter` and used `android` namespace instead of `app` in xml

Answer (score 35):

When data binding is used, we strip values from the XML. You can add a default value to be used when it is stripped to avoid the issue.

see: http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html (bottom of the page).

```
android:layout_height="@{loginVM.compact ? @dimen/verificationHeightCompact : @dimen/verificationHeightFull, default=wrap_content}"
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me: `Error:(13, 34) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_width' with parameter type float on android.widget.LinearLayout. `

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro please check my answer below

Comment: what is we want to set calculated height instead of from xml?

Answer (score 14):

I solved it like this in **Kotlin** instead of **Java**.

Make a file called

```
MyBindings.kt
```

And put in:

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:customHeight")
fun setLayoutHeight(view: View, height: Float) {
    view.layoutParams = view.layoutParams.apply { this.height = height.toInt() }
}
```

And then you can use this in your layouts:

```
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/internalTopDisplay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
bind:customHeight="@{loginVM.compact ? @dimen/verificationHeightCompact : @dimen/verificationHeightFull}"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

According to the discussion on Android issue tracker, it is impossible to set layout height or width with data binding without creating custom binding adapters:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180666

The binding adapter needed for setting view height would look like that:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_height")
public static void setLayoutHeight(View view, int height) {
    LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it saved me hours of searching!

Comment: didn't work for me, I got "you must supply a layout_height attribute"

Answer (score 5):

For me did this the trick:

```
    @BindingAdapter("android:layout_height")
    public static void setLayoutHeight(View view, final Number height) {
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height =  height.intValue();
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```

And the xml:

```
android:layout_height="@{item.isItemCollapsed ? @dimen/radar_item_first_background_height  : item.textMaxLines, default=@dimen/radar_item_first_background_height}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a binding adapter for **android:layout_height** that takes in a float.

For **height**:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_height")
    public static void setLayoutHeight(View view, float height) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = (int) height;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```

For **width:**

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
public static void setLayoutWidth(View view, float height) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = (int) height;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
android:layout_width="@{model.isBig ? @dimen/big_dimen : @dimen/small_dimen, default=wrap_content}"

android:layout_height="@{model.isBig ? @dimen/big_dimen : @dimen/small_dimen, default=wrap_content}"
```

**PS**:
Don't forget to set a default value

Answer (score 1):

This is a neat, scalable mechanism for switching between two `layout_height` or `layout_width` states using a boolean. You would need to import the LayoutWidthHeightBindingAdapterVariants class into layout to specify one of its values in the layout:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["android:layout_height", "app:layout_widthHeightVariant"])
fun expandContractHeight(view: View, flag: Boolean, variant: LayoutWidthHeightBindingAdapterVariants) {
    val params = view.layoutParams
    params.height = if (flag) variant.valueWhenTrue else variant.valueWhenFalse
    view.layoutParams = params
    view.invalidate()
}

@BindingAdapter(value = ["android:layout_width", "app:layout_widthHeightVariant"])
fun expandContractWidth(view: View, flag: Boolean, variant: LayoutWidthHeightBindingAdapterVariants) {
    val params = view.layoutParams
    params.height = if (flag) variant.valueWhenTrue else variant.valueWhenFalse
    view.layoutParams = params
    view.invalidate()
}

enum class LayoutWidthHeightBindingAdapterVariants(val valueWhenFalse: Int, val valueWhenTrue: Int) {
    // format: <falseValue>_TO_<trueValue>
    WRAP_TO_MATCH(WRAP_CONTENT, MATCH_PARENT),
    MATCH_TO_WRAP(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT),
    WRAP_TO_ZERODP(WRAP_CONTENT, 0),
    ZERODP_TO_WRAP(0, WRAP_CONTENT)
}
```