# Arithmetic operations in layout - Android Data Binding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I'm trying to use arithmetic operation in data binding:

```
<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@{2 * @dimen/button_min_height}" />
```

Unfortunately I'm getting:

```
Error:(47, 47) must be able to find a common parent for int and float
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can achieve this with a `BindingAdapter`, which uses the `layout_height` and a `factor`. I don't know if it works "out of the box"...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you are performing `int * float` operation, 2 is `int` value and `@dimen/button_min_height` will give you `float` value. However `android:layout_height` will accept `float` value only.

You can create your custom binding method like this :

```
public class Bindings {
    @BindingAdapter("android:layout_height")
    public static void setLayoutHeight(View view, float height) {
       ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
       layoutParams.height = (int) height;
       view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
}
```

and in your xml code

```
android:layout_height="@{(float)2 * @dimen/activity_vertical_margin}"
```

convert 2 into `float` so it will not give you any casting error.

From above code you will get `RunTimeException : You must supply 
a layout_height attribute.`, inorder to solve that error, provide `default` value to `layout_height`

```
android:layout_height="@{(float)2 * @dimen/activity_vertical_margin, default=wrap_content}"
```

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#studio_support) official docs for `default` attribute concept, or you can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35332242/3134215) as well

Comment: Unfortunately after that:

    android:layout_height="@{(float)2 * @dimen/button_min_height, default=wrap_content}"
I'm getting: 
Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_height' with parameter type float on android.widget.Space.

Comment: Have you declared `BindingAdapter` method?

Comment: Forgot to rebuild. Now is working!
I decided to cast dimen to int because ViewGroup.LayoutParams.height is int. Could you consider editing your answer or there is an reason of casting to float?

Comment: Both will work, but as `layout_height` is made to accept float value, i have not changed in that. It is better if we keep default behaviour as it is. Otherwise choice is yours :)

Answer (score -3):

You should do this programmatically. In your xml file add android:id attribute to your Space view :

```
<Space
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In your Java class you should wirte this :

```
Space space = findViewById(R.id.space);
space.getLayoutParams().height = 2 * getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.button_min_height);
space.requestLayout();
```

Comment: I know I can. But my question was regarding data binding.