# default value gives error in data binding

Tags: android, layout, android-databinding

I am implementing `Data Binding` to set height and width of View. Here is the code i have tried.

```
android:layout_height="@{@dimen/main_layout_height, default=wrap_content}"
```

as per yigit's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35332242/3134215) and from Data Binding [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#studio_support) i have used `default` attribute, but it is giving following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mTheme in class Landroid/content/res/Resources$Theme; (declaration of 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources(MonkeyPatcher.java:374)
at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.restart(Server.java:523)
at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.access$600(Server.java:61)
at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server$SocketServerReplyThread.handle(Server.java:318)
at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server$SocketServerReplyThread.run(Server.java:190)
at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server$SocketServerThread.run(Server.java:158)
```