# How can I bind layout_width value with ViewModel using databinding

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

It seems not very straight forward to databind layout_width or other layout properties.
If I try bind it directly like `android:layout_width="@{viewModel.heading3.width}` -> it doesn't compile.

After adding a binding adapter like below It throws runtime exception to supply layout_width

```
    @BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
public static void setLayoutWidth(View view, int width) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = width;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

How can I achieve textview height and weight controlled by Model using databinding. I can try it in code behind but to me databinding approach seems more suitable for my scenario.

Thanks.

Edit:
As suggested I have gone through but my question is different from: [Android Data Binding layout_width and layout_height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295120/android-data-binding-layout-width-and-layout-height)

I am not planning to read Width value from  dimen xml, I want to read it from viewModel. This is how my viewModel looks

```
public class HeadingViewModel {
public HeadingViewModel(String heading, int width) {
    this.heading = heading;
    this.width = width;
}

String heading;
int width;

public String getHeading() {
    return heading;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}
```

Then I am now trying to use default value like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="@{viewModel.heading1.width, default=match_parent}"
    android:layout_height="50dp" android:text="@{viewModel.heading1.heading}" android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
```

Still this databinding is NOT working. Let me know if I am still missing something in suggested thread.

Comment: Refer [Android Data Binding layout\_width and layout\_height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295120/android-data-binding-layout-width-and-layout-height)

Comment: @RaviRupareliya let me know if you still see this as duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with a `float` value, it will work

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
public static void setLayoutWidth(View view, float width) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = (int)width;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

and change datatype of `width` also it in your `HeadingViewModel`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Can you suggest why we have to convert to float from int and then back?

Comment: I was also wondering the same, first i have tries with `int` only but got an error says `you must specify attribute layout_width`. So i thought to give it a try with `float` and it worked