# BottomSheet is stretched full screen

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, bottom-sheet

I am using databinding for the bottomsheet, but when I add

> setContentView(binding.root)

it stretches layout to full screen
If I remove *setContentView* though, view still shows but there is no binding. Here is my code:

```
val binding : BottomSheetStationViewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this),
            R.layout.bottom_sheet_view, null, false)
    binding.data = data
    setContentView(binding.root)
```

here is the layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
<variable
    name="data"
    type="com.example.Data"/>
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

... 
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: can you add your layout `bottom_sheet_view`

Comment: I did but it shows well unless I do setContentView

Comment: inside your linear layout do you have any tag which is match_parent then make it wrap_content

Comment: no I do not have. I think the problem is in setContentView as it's setting/modifying activity's view

Comment: This link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295120/android-data-binding-layout-width-and-layout-height