# Android Databinding not working to set dimens with ternary conditional

Tags: android, data-binding, resources, dimensions

I'm trying to use a boolean from a View Model to determine which dimension to use for certain attributes by using it in a ternary operation. The problem is the compiler says the attribute cannot be set with a float

My Code:

```
android:layout_marginTop="@{landingManager.messageClickable ? @dimen/spacing_2 : @dimen/spacing_13}"
```

The Dimension Resources:

```
<dimen name="spacing_2">2dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_13">13dp</dimen>
```

The Error:

```
ERROR: Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.TextView android:layout_marginTop> that accepts parameter type 'float'
```

Note: I can actually ctrl+click on the resource declarations in the XML that will open up the dimens file to those lines. So I know that the IDE is properly linking those

What is so weird is that this working for my textSize attribute

```
android:textSize="@{landingManager.messageClickable ? @dimen/sp_18 : @dimen/sp_13}"
```

So I am totally lost as to why a dimension resource in dp doesn't work, but a resource in sp does.

Comment: It's not the resource or the conditional operator that's the problem. It's that there is no `setLayoutMarginTop()` method, like there is a `setTextSize()` method. The `android:layout_*` attributes are actually settings for the `View`'s `LayoutParams`, rather than for the `View` itself, so they have to be handled a little differently. AFAIK, this still requires a custom binding adapter (though I haven't done anything with data binding in a while); e.g., something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/42264988.

Comment: Because that's a regular attribute setting that won't be touched by the data binding framework, so it'll just be set through the normal mechanisms during layout inflation.